# Assign values lead / lag like within one table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am struggling to solve one problem that the best if would be fixed using SQL instead of python/bash scripting.
The idea is to calculate the time difference between states per object for state **NO**. I was thinking to add a fourth column and I managed to do something but it works very slow even for a short time period (impossible to run it in intervals 5-10min).
I am using MySQL 5.7.

The table looks like this:

| EVENT | OBJECT | STATE | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CAR | NO | 25.01.2022 10:00 |
| 2 | LAMP | NO | 25.01.2022 10:00 |
| 3 | CAR | OK | 25.01.2022 10:05 |
| 4 | CAR | NO | 25.01.2022 10:08 |
| 5 | CAR | OK | 25.01.2022 10:10 |
| 6 | LAMP | OK | 25.01.2022 10:30 |
| 7 | LAMP | NO | 25.01.2022 10:32 |
| 8 | WINDOW | NO | 25.01.2022 10:10 |
| 9 | WINDOW | OK | 25.01.2022 10:20 |
| 10 | LAMP | OK | 25.01.2022 10:50 |

---

Desired table:

| EVENT | OBJECT | STATE | TIMESTAMP | TIMEDIF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CAR | NO | 25.01.2022 10:00 | 5 |
| 2 | LAMP | NO | 25.01.2022 10:00 | 30 |
| 4 | CAR | NO | 25.01.2022 10:08 | 2 |
| 7 | LAMP | NO | 25.01.2022 10:32 | 18 |
| 8 | WINDOW | NO | 25.01.2022 10:10 | 10 |

---

My SQL example:

```
SELECT 
  EVENT, 
  OBJECT, 
  STATE, 
  TIMESTAMP, 
  (
    (
      select 
        min(TIMESTAMP) 
      from 
        events events2 
      where 
        events1.OBJECT = events2.OBJECT 
        and events2.EVENT > events1.EVENT 
        and events2.STATE = 'NO'
    )
  ) STATE_NO 
FROM 
  events events1 
WHERE 
  events1.OBJECT = 'YES' "
```

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:
EXPLAIN of actual query (time interval -20days):

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | events1 | NULL | ALL | events_1,events_2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 5088944 | 1.08 | Using where; Using temporary |
| 1 | PRIMARY | t | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | zabbix.comtab.objectid | 1 | 29.63 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | f | NULL | ref | functions_1,functions_2 | functions_1 | 8 | zabbix.comtab.objectid | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | PRIMARY | i | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,items_1 | PRIMARY | 8 | zabbix.f.itemid | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | PRIMARY | h | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | zabbix.i.hostid | 1 | 10.00 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | events2 | NULL | ALL | PRIMARY | NULL | NULL | NULL | 5088944 | 0.11 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1) |

Joined tables in actual queries do not disturb the performance.

Comment: 'I am using MySQL 6.0' - there wasn't a mysql version 6 ?

Comment: Actually it is mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19-17, for Linux (x86_64) using 6.0, sorry! 5.7

Comment: Then lead and lag are not possibilities - can you upgrade to 8?

Comment: No, it is not possible. The problem is to assign timestamp of state YES to NO, as you can see in the described tables.

Comment: Please recheck your SQL.  Are you sure it's logically correct?  `WHERE events1.OBJECT = 'YES'` does not appear correct.  How could you get any result with that logic?  Beyond that, for performance questions, please provide the exact schema (create table statements, with indexes), and the result of: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Added @JonArmstrong

Answer (score 0):

Let's turn it around.  Instead of computing the information *after the fact*, let's compute it *as new data arrives*.  And, let's have a new table `Current` with the current state of each sensor.  This is in addition to `History` (like what you have now) and `Desired`.

When a new sensor status comes in, and it says `OK`, check to see if `Current` says `NO` for that device.  This is a trivial `SELECT`.  If changing from `NO` to `OK`, the `INSERT` a row into `Desired`.  (Also trivial.)

Or this could be embodied in a Trigger (`ON UPDATE of Current`), using `OLD.state = 'NO' AND NEW.state = 'OK'`, plus `TO_SECONDS(NEW.timestamp) - TO_SECONDS(OLD.timestamp)` as `timediff`.

If you have a lot of data already and need to build `Current`, I would pretend to "replay" all the `History`.  Since this is a one-time setup, the performance is not an issue.